# Solving XX'=Y for X when X is rectangular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $X$ is unknown real-valued $m$-by-$n$ matrix where $m\ne n$ and $Y$ is known. What is the approach for solving $$XX^t=Y$$?

Comment: Is X' the transpose of X? I know the apostrophe is used in some coding languages, but it may help to clarify to write X^T instead..

Answer (score 0):

You may find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $Y$ which happen to be the square of the singular values and left singular vectors of $X$ respectively, and recover $X$ from its SVD.

Comment: I've just noticed that I had written the "square roots" of the singular values instead of just "square". I changed it